# Why do we use binomial coefficients when finding probabilities of outcomes of multiple coin flips?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, binomial-coefficients

What is the probability that we get exactly two heads when we flip a coin five times? The answer is apparently $5\choose2$, i.e. $\frac {5!}{2!3!} $

But I the way I learned it, the "choose" notation is to be used when counting possible subsets of a set. For example, $5\choose2$ is the number of ways to choose a $2$-length subset of a $5$-length set.

How can I reconcile that definition with the application here? The only thing relating this problem to a set-counting problem is writing out the outcomes as a $5$-length set. For example, {H,H,T,T,T} represents the event of getting two heads.

But there are repetitions in that "set", so why do we use the choose notation for it?

Furthermore, it would seem that {H,H,T,T,T} is a different event than {H,T,T,T,H}. Is that true? Because if so, the "set" is ordered, which is another reason why it doesn't make sense to use $n\choose k$ here: we are a this point dealing with lists (which are ordered and allow repetition).

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I've been struggling with this for a long time and I'd hugely appreciate any help.

Comment: It's easiest to treat the five flips as an ordered sequence even though the event "exactly two heads" doesn't require it. The reason is that there are $2^5=32$ EQUALLY LIKELY ordered sequences of 5 flips, of which $C(5,2)=10$ contain exactly 2 heads, so the desired probability is $10/32$ (choose 2 pf the 5 positions for the two ends -- that's where the "counting subsets" happens).

Comment: The probability cannot be larger than $1$, so you want to divide ${5\choose 2}$ by $2^5$.

Comment: @uniquesolution Moreover, the value of $\binom52$ is a nonnegative integer.

Comment: @Ned That should be an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets are not ordered.  However, the outcomes in question are finite sequences of heads and tails.  The sequence $(H, H, T, T, T)$ is different from $(H, T, T, T, H)$ since the heads and tails appear in a different order.

The number $\binom{5}{2}$ counts the number of sequences of length five in which exactly two heads appear.  What we are choosing is the positions where the heads appear in the sequence.  However, $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ is not a probability since a probability must lie between $0$ and $1$ inclusive.

If we make the assumption that heads and tails are equally likely outcomes, then there are $2^5 = 32$ equally likely possible sequences of heads and tails since there are two equally likely ways to fill each of the five positions in the sequence.

Under this assumption, the probability that exactly two heads appear in five tosses of the coin is
$$\Pr(\text{exactly two heads}) = \frac{\binom{5}{2}}{2^5} = \frac{10}{32}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! That all makes sense, and indeed it was a silly mistake to think that 10 could be a probability. My lack of conceptual understanding persists, but I think it best that I express that in a different post as to avoid making an annoyingly long comment. But your explanation helped me a lot: thank you again!

Comment: @N. F. Taussig 'The number $\binom{5}{2}$ counts the number of sequences of length five in which exactly two heads appear.' Would you mind elaborating a bit on that please? Because as far as $\binom{5}{2}$ is concerned (H,H,T,T,T) and (H,T,T,T,H) count as 1 right? But surely for the purpose of counting the number of 2-heads length 5 sequence we need to distinguish between the two?

Comment: @DanielMak There are ten sequences of length five composed of heads and tails with exactly two heads: \begin{align*}(H, H, T, T, T),\\ (H, T, H, T, T),\\ (H, T, T, H, T),\\ (H, T, T, T, H),\\ (T, H, H, T, T),\\ (T, H, T, H, T),\\ (T, H, T, T, H),\\ (T, T, H, H, T),\\ (T, T, H, T, H),\\ (T, T, T, H, H) \end{align*}  The reason there are $10$ such sequences is that each such sequence is completely determined by choosing which two of the five positions in the sequence will be filled with heads, which can be done in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks that helped a lot